Is javassist compatible with Hibernate 3?
I'm trying to get javassist working with Hibernate 3.1 and it doesn't seem to make any difference to the problem I'm facing - complaints about missing getters or setters in entity classes. (Since these are actually autogenerated, and there are roughly a thousand of them, I don't want to have to add them - hence the desire to use javassist.)
I don't want to upgrade Hibernate - too much work fixing compile errors in hundreds of test cases.
My question is, what version of javassist should I use to be compatible with Hibernate 3.1.3? And should simply importing the dependency via maven/pom.xml be enough, or are there in fact extra steps I need to follow?
